# Using an EFI partition to install an OS instead of bootable USB stick, is it possible?

Tags: boot, installation, operating-systems, uefi, bootable-media

I found myself with no spare DVDs and no USB stick when I wanted to install a new OS on my laptop, so I started thinking about the UEFI boot process that I recently had done some tinkering with.

Instead of creating a bootable USB or DVD, could I (theoretically) install an OS by making a new UEFI entry somehow? They're bootable.

If no, why not?

(I'm a developer that realized I don't know much about OS install processes)

Comment: sorry, this is seems like a alot of drama for something that a 5 dollar usb thumbdrive can solve easily. good luck tho

Comment: I think you mistake me for someone who is interested in knowing how to buy a thumb drive, when in fact I'm interested in the OS install process. I must have been unclear about that. Besides, offering an installer that can do this is hardly more drama than asking users to go to a store or wait days for an online order. I see no problem with asking about this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The details vary with the OS, though. Many Linux installers, for instance, look for files on a filesystem that has a particular name, so you'd need to set the name for the partition that holds a copy of those installation files. Broadly speaking, you'd need to prepare a partition to hold the installation files and then set it running. (This partition might or might not be the same as the ESP; that depends on how the installer is written.)

If you want to understand the EFI boot process better, you might want to check out [my Web page on EFI boot loaders.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) It's got some basic theoretical information, as well as more practical information on installation and on several Linux boot loaders for EFI. Once the kernel is running, the installation process is pretty similar whether the installation is to an EFI computer or a BIOS computer. (There are a few differences related to partitioning and boot loader installation, though.)

Comment: Thanks, I read up a lot on your page while doing the tinkering, very educational. Ok, so the only reason people use a USB stick and DVD is because otherwise they'd have to go into the firmware and change the boot order to a custom partition that could potentially be created with an installer wizard?

Comment: The only reason that *people* do it is because that's the way the *distribution maintainers* have set it up. As to why distribution maintainers set it up that way, you'd need to ask them. Few people involved in such decision-making post here.